# Mounting Qnap NAS - Ubutnu

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, network-storage, qnap

I would like to mount my qnap to my Linux Mint laptop.
The IP address of the NAS is : 192.168.0.25

So I executed this command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o username=user_name,password=my_password 192.168.0.25:HR /mnt/qnap
```

I had this error:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

When I use the UI and click on Network then MyNas icon, I had this error:

```
Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused
```

Do you see any solution ?

== Update ==

This is the showmount command output:

```
showmount -e 192.168.0.25

Export list for 192.168.0.25:
/homes       
/my_home       
/Web         
/Public      
/OceanKTV    
/Multimedia  
/Download    
/Container
```

Comment: Not 100% sure this question's right for serverfault but either way what happens when you do 'showmount -e 192.168.0.25'?

Comment: @Chopper3 thanks. Please see the update in my post.

Comment: Ok...so which mountpoint are you going for, there's not one called 'HR'

Comment: mounting any of these folders gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is neither a `username` nor a `password` option for NFS mounts. A typical NFS mount command looks like as follows.

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.25:/Multimedia /mnt
```

For further mount options you can refer to the manpage of NFS.

Comment: why shouldn't I put a login/password ? How can I authenticate then ? I found this in https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Mounting_an_NFS_share_on_Ubuntu

Comment: Because NFS does not work that way. Unless you have NFSv4, there is no user authentication. With NFSv4, the only way for authentication is kerberos, which does not need username/password but works with "tickets". In NFSv3 and below, you only can allow/disallow a network segment or single hosts or netgroups.